# Why I cannot use where & orderby from FirebaseFirestore.instance in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Why I cannot use where & orderby from FirebaseFirestore in flutter

in my code

```
body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('Posts')
            .where('imageType', isEqualTo: 'image')
            .orderBy('time', descending: true) 
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context,
            AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => PostCard(
              snap: snapshot.data!.docs[index],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
```

I will got error.

```
itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length
```

Error code

```
Exception has occurred.
_CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)
```

Where has problem?

Answer (score 0):

Data can be null, so using your snapshot.data! bang operator will give you that error. By using ! you basically tell the compiler that you promise the value will not be null at that point. However, it is in your case :)

Consider implementing some sort of loading indicator that is returned instead of whatever you are building when you got actual data :)

The where and orderBy have nothing to do with your issue btw.

Comment: But I've a data from firebasestore

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like a loading indicator to wait until data comes so it will not be null

For example in your stream builder you can use something like

```
if (!snapshot.hasData)
   return Center(
       child: CircularProgressIndicator());
return TheWidgetYouWantToBuildWhenDataComes();
```

Comment: I'd used this methods, but still error.

Comment: I updated my context